# JPA: Deletion with Foreign Keys in ManyToMany and ManyToOne relations?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot to model my backend and I have several foreign keys in my model structure.

I am unable to run delete operations in general and update operations when foreign keys are affected. I have tried several methods found on the internet but none seem to work.

[image]

Via SQL (SQL commands) can delete entities from book_queue_entry, copy and author_write but not author, book and book_store user due to foreign key constraints. Therefore I'd like to know what I am doing wrong in each of my models/relationships that don't work on SQL level. 
Since it does not work on SQL level something with my modelling, at least as far as configuring on delete operations is fundamentally wrong. I can't point my finger at what.

Problem 1: Cannot delete a book: When a book is deleted, it should be deleted from the list of works of an author - in other words, it should be deleted from authors_write:

Author.java:

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Author extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    //stuff

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(
            name = "authors_write",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    Set<Book> works;
}
```

Book.java

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    //stuff

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "works", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Set<Author> authors;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book")
    private List<BookQueueEntry> bookQueue;
}
```

Problem 2: Cannot delete Authors. When an author is deleted then all entries in authors_write with the corresponding author_id should be deleted. The classes are the same as above. Cascading does not work in this case either.

Problem 3: Cannot delete Users. When users are deleted borrower_id in copy should be nulled (I've read this does not work in JPA at all) and book_queue_entries with corresponding user_id should be deleted

Copy.java

```
@Entity
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Copy extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    //stuff

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Book reference;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private BookStoreUser borrower;
}
```

User.java:

```
public class BookStoreUser extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    //more stuff here 

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "borrower")
    private Set<Copy> booksBorrowed;

}
```

BookQueueEntry.java

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class BookQueueEntry extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    //more stuff here

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private BookStoreUser user;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", nullable = false)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Book book;


}
```

Once again, I believe something is wrong with how I've mapped the cascading operations. Something is wrong in a more general sense and I cant figure out what.

EDIT: I should note that `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` did not work for me either. 
EDIT 2: With a clear head, I've been able to fix Problems 1 and 2 using this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYNdjtf7iAQ

Comment: For Problem 1 and 2, see this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYNdjtf7iAQ

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYNdjtf7iAQ

My problems are solved but when deleting Users it throws a  ConcurrentModificationException which is not really related to this problem.

My classes now look like this:

Book.java

```
public class Book extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String isbn;

    @NotBlank
    private String title;

    private Integer year;

    private String imageUrl;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "works")
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    Set<Author> authors;

    private Boolean isAvailable;

    private Integer version;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Language language;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reference", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Copy> copies;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<BookQueueEntry> bookQueue;

    // see here why: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vYNdjtf7iAQ
    public void addAuthor(Author author) {
        this.authors.add(author);
        author.getWorks().add(this);
    }

    public void removeAuthor(Author author) {
        this.authors.remove(author);
        author.getWorks().remove(this);
    }
}
```

Author.java:

```
public class Author extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(
            name = "authors_write",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    Set<Book> works;

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.works.add(book);
        book.addAuthor(this);
    }

    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        this.works.remove(book);
        book.removeAuthor(this);
    }
}
```

Copy.java:

```
public class Copy extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Book reference;

    private LocalDate borrowedAt;

    private LocalDate dueDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private BookStoreUser borrower;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Location location;

    public void addBorrower(BookStoreUser user) {
        user.addBorrowedCopy(this);
    }

    public void removeBorrower(BookStoreUser user) {
        user.removeBorrowedCopy(this);
    }
}
```

BookStoreUser.java

```
public class BookStoreUser extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @NotNull
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    private boolean isAdmin;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "borrower", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Copy> booksBorrowed;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    public void addBorrowedCopy(Copy copy) {
        this.booksBorrowed.add(copy);
        copy.setBorrower(this);
        copy.setBorrowedAt(LocalDate.now());
        copy.setDueDate(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1));
    }

    public void removeBorrowedCopy(Copy copy) {
        this.booksBorrowed.remove(copy);
        copy.setBorrower(null);
        copy.setBorrowedAt(null);
        copy.setDueDate(null);
    }
}
```

And also make sure to make use of the utility methods in the service layer like this:

```
public Long deleteById(Long id) {
    this.validator.checkIDNotNull(id);
    Book book = em.find(Book.class, id);
    for (Author author : book.getAuthors()) {
        book.removeAuthor(author);
    }
    bookRepository.deleteById(id);
    validator.checkEntityNotExists(id);
    return id;
}

public Book create(Book book) {
    this.checkISBNIsValid(book.getIsbn());
    this.checkISBNExists(book.getIsbn());
    this.checkEntityHasValues(book);
    for (Author author : book.getAuthors()) {
        author.addBook(book);
    }
    log.info("Book with ISBN {} created successfully", book.getId());
    return bookRepository.save(book);
}
```

EDIT: ConcurrentModificationException: Deleting from a list/Set will throw this problem.  This can be found on SO - to fix ConcurrentModificationExceptions you have to create a new HashSet with whatever is throwing that problem and iterate through that:

```
new HashSet<Author>(book.getAuthors())
        .forEach(author -> book.removeAuthor(author));
```